# Is there a foldLeft operator equivalent on a 1.4 Apache Flink DataStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a stream setup like this using Apache Flink 1.4
       starts with  DataStream
        then keyBy
        then window
        then aggregate

the output of the aggregate operation is an AggregateResult object
so the stream as it ends now is of type SingleOutputStreamOperator

What I would like to do next is the equivalent of a scala foldLeft.  Is there an operator that provides that functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flink 1.4 provides the [`AggregateFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#aggregatefunction) that is similar to a `foldLeft`.

The [API of the AggregateFunction](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.4/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/AggregateFunction.java) works as follows: The initial (or start) value is defined in the `createAccumulator()` method. The accumulator holds the partially aggregated value. Values are aggregated into the accumulator with the `add()` method. Finally, the result is computed from the accumulator by the`getResult()` method.

The difference to a `foldLeft` is that an `AggregateFunction` is able to merge its accumulators (partial aggregates) via its `merge()` method. The ability to merge partial aggregates is required for some window types (session windows) and useful for certain optimizations.